# Raising an event after a keypress

Tags: krl

Aaron Frost's [TweetPlus app](http://apps.kynetx.com/installable_apps/2533-TweetPlus) has a useful feature in which the tweet functionality of the app lies dormant until the user presses Ctrl+Alt+T. At that time, a notify box pops up in the upper right corner to let the user tweet about the page they are on. I would like to do something similar.

Is there a way to use `watch()` to raise an event when the user presses a certain key combination?

Another possibility: Is there a way to raise an event directly with JavaScript, including sending event parameters? This way, I can set up a callback (perhaps using [jQuery HotKeys](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys)) to raise the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steve, here is my answer. Let me know if there are questions or feedback? http://www.40win.com/2011/05/08/jskeyboardevents/

Comment: This would be cool to have built in the runtime, so you could raise an event on a keyboard combination.